# How to share one api call to different resource names in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-admin

I'm using react-admin and I have the following resources:

[image]

So What I need from here is to add a `Images` and a `videos` resource. Something like this:

[image]

So as you can see in the image above,`Images` and `Videos` **SHOULD** come from the same endpoint which is called `Post`.

Now, what I showed you in the image it doesn't actually work. why? Because I don't have an `Image` or a `Videos` endpoint. Each time I click on them it will take me to `http://localhost:3000/dahboard/Images` or `http://localhost:3000/dahboard/Videos`, which again does not exist. My `Posts` endpoint does have the content that I need, it has images and it has videos.

### What I need

What I need is something to be shown like in the image I posted. Something where I can click on `Images` or `Videos` no matter if the endpoint goes directly to `http://localhost:3000/dahboard/Post`. But I can't seem to find something related in the react-admin documentation.

### What I currently Have

```
<Admin 
      layout={MyLayout} 
      theme={theme} 
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <Resource name="Post"  {...posts} icon={ImageIcon} />
      <Resource name="Comment" {...comments} icon={ChatIcon} />
      <Resource name="User" {...users} icon={PeopleIcon} />
</Admin>
```

### Folder Structure

```
|-- node_modules
|-- public
|-- src
  |---- comments
  |---- components
  |---- pages
  |---- posts
    |--- index.js
    |--- PostList.js
    |--- PostShow.js
  |---- users
    |--- index.js
    |--- UserList.js
    |--- UserShow.js
  |---- util
  |---- videos 
    |--- index.js
    |--- VideoList.js
    |--- VideoShow.js
```

### EDIT

This is how I configured my dataProvider, I am using Hasura's data provider for this:

```
function DashboardPage(props) {
  const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const buildDataProvider = async () => {

      const myClientWithAuth = new ApolloClient({
        uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        headers: {
          'x-hasura-admin-secret':
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
        },
      });

      const dataProvider = await buildHasuraProvider({
        client: myClientWithAuth,
        getList: (resource, params) => {
          const {page, perPage} = params.pagination;
          const {field, order} = params.sort;
          const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
          };
          const endpoint = resource === 'images' || resource === 'videos' 
            ? 'posts'
            : resource;

          const url = `${apiUrl}/${endpoint}?${stringify(query)}`;
          
          return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
            data: json,
            total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
          }));
        }
      })

      setDataProvider(() => dataProvider);
      
    };
    buildDataProvider();
  }, []);

  if (!dataProvider) return <p>Loading...</p>;

return (
    <Admin 
      layout={MyLayout} 
      theme={theme} 
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <Resource name="Post" {...posts} icon={ImageIcon}  />
      <Resource name="Comment" {...comments} icon={ChatIcon} />
      <Resource name="User" {...users} icon={PeopleIcon} />
    </Admin>
  );
```

Comment: You can implement your dataProvider and replace paths inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right place to put that logic is in the `dataProvider`. You can map resource names to different endpoints. Something like:

```js
const dataProvider = {
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
        };
        const endpoint = resource === 'images' || resources = 'videos'
           ? 'posts'
           : resource; 
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${endpoint}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
            data: json,
            total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
        }));
    },
   // ...
}
```

Comment: OMG, let me try this and I'll come back!

Comment: Hello, came back sorry. Well, this kinda works although I don't see any output out of it. I edited my post so you can see how I have it implemented

Comment: Any idea of what am I doing wrong? I'll appreciate it a lot!